# Figure 2.5 in Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: r, machine-learning, bayesian, knn

I met some difficulty in calculating the Bayes decision boundary of Figure 2.5. In the package ElemStatLearn, it already calcualted the probability at each point and used contour to draw the boundary. Can any one tell me how to calculate the probability? Thank you very much.

In traditional Bayes decision problem, the mixture distribution are usually normal distribution, but in this example, it uses two steps to generate the samples, so I have some difficulty in calculating the distribution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I feel your question is very vague, answerable only to those familiar with figure 2.5 of that particular work you mention. Perhaps you could expand your answer to include relevant information?

Comment: That is the exact boundary for the situation where the generating densities are known. The estimated decision boundary given the sample is quite different. Are you trying to compute the real boundary given that we know how the data were generated, or the naive Bayes estimate of the boundary?

Comment: Thank you very much. The procedure is illustrated by bogatron as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 2.3.3 of ESL (accessible online) states how the data were generated.  Each class is a mixture of 10 Gaussian distributions of equal covariance and each of the 10 means are drawn from another bivariate Gaussian, as specified in the text.  To calculate the exact decision boundary of the simulation in Figure 2.5, you would need to know the particular 20 means (10 for each class) that were generated to produce the data but those values are not provided in the text.

However, you can generate a new pair of mixture models and calculate the probability for each of the two classes (BLUE & ORANGE) that you generate.  Since each of the 10 distributions in a class are equally likely, the class-conditional probability p(x|BLUE) is just the average of the probabilities for each of the 10 distributions in the BLUE model.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand that much better. So those 20 means can be considered know when we calculate the decision boundary. That seems easier to solve it.